# UBUNTU 22.04 Does Not Boot!

Tags: grub2, 22.04

Folio 9470M). I have reinstalled ubuntu 22.04 almost 30 times at this point and still no reasonable result!

Sometimes I'll see error messages like these:

```
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 26s! [migration/0:14]

watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 26s! [kworker/u16:1:96]
```

After a fresh install, ubuntu would not boot; however when I look at the boot devices menu, I find "ubuntu" there which I am able to click on and boot into ubuntu normally (as first successful boot after installation). When the laptop is restarted, ubuntu doesn't boot and the "ubuntu" entry the boot devices list disappears.

Then on a second restart of the laptop, GRUB loads and I can select ubuntu, however the `soft lookup` error messages start again.

This is really disappointing. I was really looking forward to 22.04 ever since I started using ubuntu in 18.04 and now the installation experience has gone down the abyss.

**UPDATE**

This has to be the strangest ubuntu release of all time for me.

- Live USB **CANNOT boot** in UEFI mode: When I select "try and install ubuntu" from the grub menu while the laptop is in UEFI mode, the shows a black screen and after sometime, some errors about the CPU having a soft lockup!?
- Live USB **ONLY boots** in Legacy mode: After successfully installing ubuntu with the Live USB now it's time to restart the computer. After removing the thumb drive and clicking `ENTER` the system restarts and then shows the No Bootable Devices error.
- After install, laptop cannot boot in UEFI or Legacy: After seeing the No Bootable Devices error, I proceed to changing the boot mode from Legacy mode (the mode in which the installer was successfully able to install in however not boot after install) to UEFI. Grub2 loads and after selecting "ubuntu", the system hangs on the following HP logo.

I have tried booting in `(safe mode)` however, when I do such, I get the same results (i.e. nothing else happens once the computer gets to display the HP logo).

**Mind you, this doesn't happen on 18.04!**

At this point, I can only imagine that this is a bug, however is there a solution to this problem? Or maybe I should've just waited for the first point release.

Comment: Check this site for HP specific non-UEFI standard  modifications -- like restrictions on the bootloader names.

Comment: @ubfan1, I honestly don't understand what I'm doing with UEFI standard modifications (like restrictions on the bootloader). It would help if you could explain further. However, I have updated the question text for more information on the topic.

I honestly should have waited for the first point release before rushing to upgrade.

Comment: We really need additional information before making suggestions.  Are you dual booting with Windows? Is your disk GPT or MSDOS partitioned? Do you have any additional video hardware like Nvidia?  Sounds like you DID boot grub in UEFI mode, got to the grub menu, then things went black -- might be a video problem.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem in the past and I had to disable Secure boot in the UEFI.

Comment: @Eduardo, I make sure that secure boot is always off. Still the problem persists.

Comment: @Eduardo, I don't have windows. I installed ubuntu as per the official instructions on their website even down to the software used to create a live usb. Again, as per the instructions, I opted for the "Erase disk and install ubuntu" option. I also don't have any additional hardware at all. No Nvidia here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is that I installed Ubuntu with both BIOS (Legacy) and UEFI partitions. You can find the instructions for how to install separately for BIOS or UEFI here: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-22-04-lts.html at topic **6b (Manual Partitioning)**.

Basically just create the UEFI and boot partitions alongside your root (and or home) partitions.