# Ubuntu 22.04 failed to boot on Intel NUC NUC9I9QNX ("Out of memory")

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I'm booting on a Thunderbold disk (Samsung SSD Portable X5). It was working great with Ubuntu 21.04, booting on a NUC 9 NUC9I9QNX and Dell XPS 13.

Upgrading on Ubuntu 22.04 make Ubuntu stop booting right after the Grub, after "Loading initramfs", then showing "Out of memory" .. "Press any key to continue", and then Kernel Panic.

Disk is still booting on Dell XPS 13. Using MainLine to upgrade kernel to 5.17.5 but no luck on the NUC, still have the same issue. Old kernel 5.13 have the exactly same issue.

My guess is that the bug is not in the Kernel, but in Grub.

Answer (score 3):

Finaly, after trying to boot on the Ubuntu Live USB 22.04, and it failed the same way (Out of memory error)

I found this thread [UBUNTU 22.04 Does Not Boot!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405270/ubuntu-22-04-does-not-boot) speaking about TPM "The out of memory error is only reasonable in the moment when your CPU tries to switch from real mode to protected mode after it has copied the kernel to RAM and starts to executing it, but fails in doing so and thus cannot allocate more than real mode memory (usually only 1MiB) and thus the kernel prints out the error. I would guess that the TPM module of your PC is responsible for this behavior. Maybe it's a built in TPM module within your CPU. (Some professional Intel/AMD CPU have this feature.) You may try to disable TPM in general, doing BIOS-Upgrade or try to use a more stable kernel."

I went to the Bios, and TPM was already disabled, but SGX was enabled.

https://ibb.co/hWWjd3Y

I disabled SGX, and the system now boot normaly !

Also, Secure Boot is disabled