# Elitebook 6930P - Ubuntu 22.04 Failed to Boot After Installation

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22 on HP Elitebook 6930p Core2Duo laptop.

See my BIOS Configuration below:

- Sata Device Mode = AHCI
- USB Legacy Support = Enabled
- Virtualization Tech = Disabled
- TXT Technology = Disabled
- UEFI Boot Mode = Disabled

After installation using the Erase Disk & automatic partition option through the USB installer, the installation was succesful, I restarted the PC and I was asked to remove the installation disk and press Enter.

After following the **Remove Installation Disk & Press Enter instruction**

I did not enable UEFI mode because I read that is better to install in non-UEFI mode if the PC is pre-2010 from here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

System restarted and says **Non-system disk or disk error**

**What I have Done**

- I booted with LiveCD (USB-installed)
- Opened GParted, switched to the Sata Disk to view the partition structure, and here is what I found:
- /dev/sda1 -- Name: unnamed (File System: grub2core.img - 1.00mb)
- /dev/sda2 -- Name: EFI System Partition (File System: fat32 - 513.00mb)
- /dev/sda3 -- Name: unnamed (File System: ext4 - 185.81GB)

**NB: The EFI parition /dev/sda2 line had a red color exclamation mark, when I clicked on it, an error message was displayed.

Error Message on EFI Partition: Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this, some operations may be unavailable. The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of software packages is require for fat32 file system support: dosfstools, mtools.**

**To know if my system booted in UEFI or Legacy mode**
I had to run this command below in terminal to check:

> [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"

The command the result below, the result showed that my installation and boot into liveUSD after the boot issue is in legacy mode:

> Legacy Boot on HDD

Any ideas for proceed from here?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: To be clear: the link you provided said to install in BIOS mode *if the other OS on your system is installed in BIOS mode*. If you are not dual-booting, you do not have to worry about the "other system," and so you can install in UEFI mode.

Comment: See this quote from the link: `As a general rule, though, UEFI mode works better in dual-boot setups with pre-installed versions of Windows 8. If you're installing Ubuntu as the sole OS on a computer, either mode is likely to work, although BIOS mode is less likely to cause problems.` I found this point to be true with this particular PC, firstly, whenever I enable UEFI, you see a warning from HP saying, it is is only recommended for development purposes only.

Comment: And I observed that when I installed in BIOS mode, the only gets to a blank page, it does not reach the point where it returns the **no system disk found**. Hence, with tthis PC (and perhaps every pre-2010 PC as recommended by Ubuntu, UEFI disk mode is likely to fail.

Comment: I also observed that a user also confirmed that failed attempt to install using UEFI Single OS here -> [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405270/ubuntu-22-04-does-not-boot)

Answer (score 2):

Having tried to fix the error displayed on GParted on the Fat32 partition created by the automatic installer.

> /dev/sda2 -- Name: EFI System Partition (File System: fat32 -
> 513.00mb)

Talking about this:

```
Error Message on EFI Partition: Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this, some operations may be unavailable. The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of software packages is require for fat32 file system support: dosfstools, mtools.
```

I discovered that error was a bug, here is what I did to troubleshoot and establish.

I simply downloaded and build a LiveUSB installed for 20.04 and installed using the same procedure I used above which has always worked especially when I do not intend to do a dual boot.

Straight up, the installation was successful in Legacy mode (without UEFI) considering that PC was a pre-2010 laptop and it successfully booted.

Perhaps Ubuntu would fix this soon, don't know how to repor this bug, but would have been interested to report it.

Comment: +1+1; I'm glad you have a working system now. Maybe if you install 'software packages is require for fat32 file system support: `dosfstools, mtools`' into the system that complains, it will work (also with 22.04 LTS)?

Answer (score 0):

Old HP computers with core2duo or first or second generation i3, i5 or i7 processors [often or always?] have a BIOS that does not want to boot into USB drives via grub unless there is an MSDOS partition table and a boot flag on the partition containing the `boot/grub` directory.

There might be similar problems also to boot from the internal drive, so I suggest that, when booted from the USB drive with Ubuntu, you

- backup everything important from the internal drive (that is not yet backed up),
- start `gparted` and create a new partition table, this time an MSDOS partition table. Save/exit from `gparted`,
- start the installer again, this time let the installer use the whole internal drive.

---

- If still problems, boot into the USB drive again start `gparted` and put a boot flag onto the main partition on the internal drive.

---

**Edit:** After some checking and discussion, I found that Ubuntu **22.04** LTS converts to GPT when using the whole drive. **So in order to get an MSDOS partition table it is necessary to do the whole partitioning manually**: to use `gparted` to create a partition where to install Ubuntu, and then in the installer select manual installation alias 'something else' and select how to use this partition (as **`/`** and use the ext4 file system).

Comment: I will try this and share feedback in a moment. Thanks for the input.

Comment: You were right actually, though I have not been able to boot. What I observed was that, even when I configure installation partitions without a Fat32, because I have installed multiple times. I observed the installation process automatically adds the Fat32 partition by itself whenever I check on GParted. In summary, I followed your advice and set a boot flag on the Fat32 partition, which means that there were two partitions with the boot flag. After attempting to boot, error was the same, no system disk available.

Comment: What happens if you remove the boot flag from the FAT32 partition?

Comment: Not booting. That was the case before I added the boot flag to the Fat32 partition.

Comment: If this does not work, you can try with [Lubuntu 22.04 LTS](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/jammy/release/), which has another installer than standard Ubuntu: Calamares (instead of Ubiquity). With an MSDOS partition table, and using the whole drive, I think Calamares can makes something that should work in the old HP. At least after adding a boot flag. -- Another advantage with Lubuntu is that it is light-weight and therefore suitable for old hardware.

Comment: Well. I also have an option for installing Ubuntu 20.04, be ause this issue does not come up on 20.04 installation process. I'm referring to the error message on the EFI partition I mentioned above.

Comment: OK, whatever you try, please share your results. Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I posted my result here as an answer, I had to roll back to 20.04, it was a bug in the installation compile process of 22.04. You can help accept and upvote it to help others.